# WPF event trigger for clear TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, mahapps.metro

So i have the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
         LostFocus="textboxNewValueCell_LostFocus"
         TextChanged="textboxNewValueCell_TextChanged"/>
```

And when press on `Clear` button i want to catch the `event`.

Is it possible ?

I did not find any `event`

Answer (score 1):

The `ClearTextButton` simply calls `Clear()` on the `TextBox`. There is no specific event raised. The best you can do is to handle the `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textboxNewValueCell_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        //the TextBox was cleared and the Button was maybe clicked...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give your TextBox a name.  Then, create a click event on the Button.  when the click event fires, handle the clearing of the TextBox in the CodeBehind.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Some Text"/>
    <Button x:Name="ClearButton" Click="ClearButton_Click"/>
</Grid>


 private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MyTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
 }
```

Comment: The ClearTextButton attached property does the job of adding a Button to the TextBox...this is not what the question is about.